# SSRS - filter on expression in report table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Let's say I have a report with following table in the body:

```
ID | Name     | FirstName  | GivenCity | RecordedCity | IsCorrectCity
1  | Gates    | Bill       | London    | New York     | No
2  | McCain   | John       | Brussels  | Brussels     | Yes
3  | Bullock  | Lili       | London    | London       | Yes
4  | Bravo    | Johnny     | Paris     | Las Vegas    | No
```

The column `IsCorrectCity` Basically includes an expression that checkes `GivenCity` and `RecordedCity` and returns a `No` if different or a `Yes` when equal.

Is it possible to add a report filter on the column `IsCorrectCity` (and how) so the users will be able to just select all records with `No` or `Yes`? I know this can be done with a parameter in the SQL query, but I would like to add it based on the expressions rather then adding more calculations and all to the query.

Comment: Should work: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156270%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: This can be done with a parameter in SSRS that the user chooses, are you happy with this? If so, instructions to follow...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-filter-report-builder-and-ssrs

Comment: @Schmocken: _" I know this can be done with a parameter in the SQL query, but I would like to add it based on the expressions rather then adding more calculations and all to the query."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter But we won't apply that to the SQL query, we can apply it to the filter that you have pointed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2013/03/02/filtering-data-without-changing-dataset-ssrs/) which explains how you can do it

> Filtering Data Without Changing Dataset [SSRS]

Comment: Yes! That did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @DenStudent Glad to help